# How to filter a MoreLikeThis Query

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, solrnet, morelikethis

I am using SOLR and trying to filter a MoreLikeThis query. Every time I do the filter I come up with zero results. Here is the code I am using:

```
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("id:" + id)
                         && !new SolrQuery("siteid:" + SiteId), new QueryOptions
{
    MoreLikeThis = new MoreLikeThisParameters(new[] { "content" })
    {
        MinDocFreq = 1,
        MinTermFreq = 1,
        Count = rows
    },
    Fields = new[] { "id" },
    OrderBy = new[] { new SortOrder("score", Order.ASC) },
    Start = start
});
```

as you can see `!new SolrQuery("site:" + SiteId)` is the filter. When I add this filter in the query I get no results.

Here is what the query does. I have a bunch of webpages in the solr index:

- id
- Title
- Content
- siteid

The morelikethis query takes a `id` then fetches similar documents. The filter is suppose to filter webpages by the siteid. When I apply the siteid filter it does not work. Any ideas on this?

Comment: My question on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832145/does-solrs-more-like-this-support-facet-queries

Comment: BTW, as an outsider to .Net, what is the {}? It doesnt seem like a C/C++ program block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to use the [MoreLikeThis handler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler), not [MoreLikeThis as a component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis).

[There is a patch](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/pull/28) implementing this in SolrNet, currently under review. I encourage you to take a look at the patch and give us feedback about it!